# Advanced warfare freezes when played

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

When ever I play advanced warfare, sometime into a round my ps3 freezes. How do I fix this? The disk has no finger prints on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try backing up the game save and uninstall it from the Playstation. Try then to reinstall the game and see what happens.

Also consider buying a cleaning disc. The disc with a little brush on it to clean the lense?

If it sounds like the disc is spinning very fast during these freezes then this is likely the cause.

Comment: you cant redowload a disk

Comment: redownload? you can tell the playstation to uninstall the game. then you can re-insert the disc and it will install again